# Update Vim to latest Version on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, vim, ubuntu-12.04

I have started to use Vim and oh boy! the learning curve is really steep.
I am using it to write code as well as any blog posts.
Recently, I came across a plugin - [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe). But while installing it, it see it requires vim 7.3.584+ and I have vim 7.3.429.

How do I update Vim? All I could find in my research is I have to build vim from source from scratch. Is there any other way that I can update Vim to a later version?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the vi/vim stackexchange site

Comment: Oh I didn't know there was a vi/vim stackexchange site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to update Vim to the latest version without removing pre-installed vim and re-installing it from scratch.

Following commands  will get the job done:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fcwu-tw/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install vim
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this PPA has no vim for Precise anymore.